# minifyEnabled causing app to crash on release mode

Tags: java, android, logging, gradle

My application was working fine on Debug mode. Unfortunately after uploading to Google Play Store I found that the app is crashing. I searched several similar questions all of which suggested to disable **Proguard** or check the Log outputs. However I have come across the following cases when using the **release** Build Variant:

**1-** In normal case when `minifyEnabled` is `true` the app crashes and I am not able to see any Log outputs. There are **No Debuggable Processes**.

```java
release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

**2-** Making `debuggable true` my app works fine. But again I am not able to see any error Logs because the app is working fine.

```java
release {
            debuggable true
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

**3-** Commenting `minifyEnabled true` the app works. But I lose minification benefits.

```java
release {
            shrinkResources true
            //minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
```

Also tried hardcoding `android:debuggable="true"` in AndroidManifest.XML which gives error.

The strange thing is that by setting debuggable to true the app works fine. I am not sure whether I should keep `debuggable true` in the release mode or disable minification, Or any other workaround to tackle this issue.

I will be very grateful if anyone could share how to solve this problem.

**UPDATE:** by running **Android Device Monitor** I was able to find the problem:

```
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806): Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 4806
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setSearchableInfo(android.app.SearchableInfo)' on a null object reference
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:3142)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v4.b.n.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v7.app.h$b.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v7.view.i.onCreatePanelMenu(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v7.app.q.j(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.support.v7.app.q$1.run(Unknown Source)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7329)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
01-28 00:28:13.764: E/AndroidRuntime(4806):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: you could use tools like Crashanlytics along with some additional progaurd configuration to find which part of the code throws error. https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/dex-and-proguard.html

Comment: I had the same issue 6 months back and solved myself. May be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/38702394/5649620

Comment: If the crash of the app happens, then you need to configure ProGuard. Concrete configuration depends on your project and its dependencies. Every project will have a different configuration.

Comment: Since my knowledge is limited on those subjects and I am short of time, I think I should let go of Minification. But I will wait for some more responses until I am convinced.

Comment: @Funwise removed my answer. Hadn't read the question clearly. Will update if I find one. Good luck

Comment: Thanks anyways. I was able to get the error using Android Device monitor. I will edit my question.

Comment: 4 years later and this is still an issue. Got calls from everywhere about app crashing in release mode and apparently, it is minifyenabled issue. Android is really crap OS and poorly managed by Gooogle

Comment: @Darush could you please elaborate how did you find the problem with avd? I have the same issue and there are no logs in release mode so I don't know what should I keep in proguard. Thank you!

Comment: @user2424380 set debugabble to true on your release build type to see the logs.

Comment: @Darush when I set debugabble to true, my app works. I have no idea why. So I need it on false to have the problem.

Comment: @user2424380 I was able to catch the error using Android Device Monitor. Unfortunately this tool is deprecated in the latest releases in favor of the Debugger window. However, if you still aren't able to see the crash logs you can either use a crash reporting tool or test your app thoroughly in release mode while debuggable is true.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like Proguard wasn't able to handle the SearchView widget properly. I added the following line to ***proguard-rules.pro*** file located inside ***app*** folder and the problem disappeared:

> -keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }

Now I don't need to set minifyEnabled to false.

#### UPDATE:

For those who still aren't able to see the error logs in the android studio or reproduce the crashes on release builds, they can use an online crash reporting tool.

Comment: I am having a similar issue that altering the -keep class values won't seem to solve. The app works fine in the emulator, but crashes on my phone. It is a shame how counterintuitive they have made Android Studio in an effort to squeeze out one more millisecond of load speed optimization.

Comment: Unfortunately for me minifyEnabled is causing a crash as well and honestly, if it's not going to work without me having to poke at it to find and explicitly call out exceptions to not minify then it's not worth the hassle. Disappointing that it doesn't just work out of the box.

Comment: Same issue with me, and I don't have any SearchView in my app, still it is crashing!! Any suggestions on this!!

Comment: You can run adb logcat in a terminal while running your app and then youll be able to see the output

Comment: The logcat option was the way to go in my case

Comment: I am getting this issue due to a Room entity class. The primary key value in my RemoteKeyEntity is non-null but somehow only after minifying code it's null and get NPE? Using `@Keep` annotation or proguard rules does not fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same app crash problem. In my case, I was reading a JSON file from **assets** and converting it to a Kotlin **data class**, using the Gson library. These were the classes:

```kotlin
data class JournalData(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
    val category: Categories
)

enum class Categories { POLITICS, SPORTS, TECHNOLOGY }
```

I came across two problems when using `minifyEnabled=true`:

1. Data class **properties** were being obfuscated with **random names**. For instance, the property `name` was being obfuscated to `XYZ`, or any other random name.
2. The *Categories* **enum class constants** were being obfuscated as well, so the parser couldn't associate the JSON text to those enum constants.

### Solution

- I added the `@Keep` annotation to both the data class and the enum class, like so:

```kotlin
@Keep
data class JournalData(
    val name: String,
    val url: String,
    val category: Categories
)

@Keep
enum class Categories { POLITICS, SPORTS, TECHNOLOGY }
```

By doing this, you're specifying that those classes and respective properties/constants can't be modified by *ProGuard* when minification is enabled.

Also, checking the logcat will help you find the exact error.

### See also:

- [Customize which code to keep](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code)

Answer (score 0):

Check the proguard rules for libs you are using in your project, maybe you need to add some specific rule

In my case, it was because of obfuscation protobuf, next rule fix the issue

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite { *; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have integrated my app with **crashlytics** and I found a **classNotFoundException** in release mode. `minifyEnabled=false` really helped me but it's not recommended as well. so, I set `minifyEnabled=true` as it **optimze** and **reduce** app **size**.
`minifyEnabled=true` **renames** **classes** and functions so it renames my class and that gave me **error**. so, I have added a line in `proguard` file to **keep** that class name, like this

proguard-rules.pro file

```
-keep class package.class
```