# Android Bundle java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, bundle

Testing my App on my personal devices and simulators with Android Studio works fine. When I load the App as a bundle on Google Play Store (and people install it) the class that queries the SQLite database returns a null value. I do not have an error to work on since locally everything works.

I Updated Android Studio and Gradle but the error persists. No errors are given when I generate the bundle. The closest I got was a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError but I am not 100% if this is the error I have to deal with.

From what I can understand the problem lies with the bundling (since it works when I test-run it). Can anyone suggest a way forward please?

Android Studio 2021.1.1 Beta 1
gradle v. 7
Windows 10 x64

Thank you

MainActivity class:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;import android.view.Window;

// Webview related
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public BrevjarWebInterface myJSInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialise JS Interface
        myJSInterface = new BrevjarWebInterface(this);

        // WebView Object
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.brevjarView);
        WebSettings settings = browser.getSettings();
        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Todo: resolve deprecated methods; https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/webkit/integration-tests/testapp/src/main/java/com/example/androidx/webkit/AssetLoaderAjaxActivity.java
        settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        settings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

        //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface 'Android' and load
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(myJSInterface, "Android");
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            browser.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        else {
            browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            // browser.evaluateJavascript("setAndroid();", null);
        }
    }

    /*  The following three override functions: onConfigurationChanged, onSaveInstanceState onRestoreInstance
     *  are used to keep the integrity of the UI when screen is rotated.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged (Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.brevjarView);
        browser.saveState(outState);
    }

    public void setMyJSInterface(BrevjarWebInterface myInterface) {
        myJSInterface = myInterface;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Context c = this.getBaseContext();
        c.setTheme(R.style.Theme_IlBrevjar);

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                switch (which){
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        //Yes button clicked
                        android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                        System.exit(1);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Exit the App?");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener);
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener);
        builder.show();
    }
```

And this is the DBHelper class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class SQLiteDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private SQLiteDBHelper mInstance = null;
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ordo_2021_10.sqlite";
    private static final String DB_PATH_SUFFIX = "/databases/";
    static Context ctx;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    /** This avoids direct instantiation and forces the creation of an object to be done
     through the getInstance method. The getInstance method prevents multiple instances
     to be created and thus avoids data leak
     */
    public SQLiteDBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        ctx = context;
    }

    public OrdoDay getOrdoDay(String date) {

        OrdoDay contList = new OrdoDay();   // only one value will be returned

        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select ld_date, lt_title, ld_litWeek, years.lt_id\n" +
                    "from years\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN liturgicalTimes on years.lt_id = liturgicalTimes.lt_id\n" +
                    "where ld_date = \"" + date + "\"", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    // Return Data: date (String),litTime (String), litWeek (int)
                    contList = new OrdoDay(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getInt(2),cursor.getInt(3));
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return contList;
    }

    public ArrayList <FeastDay> getFeastDay(String date, int dioc_id, int inst_id, int loc_id, int ch_id, int fullList) {

        String month = date.substring(5,7);
        String dom = date.substring(8,10);
        String dt = date;

        ArrayList<FeastDay> feastList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT *\n" +
                    "FROM (\n" +
                    "SELECT f.feast_title, f.feast_subtitle, institute.inst_code, institute.inst_title, diocese.dioc_title, locality.loc_title, church.ch_title, f.proprju_id, f.desc_short, f.desc_long, grade.grd_rank, grade.grd_title, colour.col_title, kp.kmn_code, kp.kmn_title, kp.para1, kp.para2, kp.para3, kp.para4, ld.lt_title, ld.ld_litWeek, diocese.dioc_id, institute.inst_id, locality.loc_id, church.ch_id, f.feast_id, fk.kmn_cnt  FROM (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM main\n" +
                    "WHERE day=" + dom + " AND month=" + month + "\n" +
                    ") m\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  institute on m.inst_id = institute.inst_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  diocese on m.dioc_id = diocese.dioc_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  locality on m.loc_id = locality.loc_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  church on m.ch_id = church.ch_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM feast\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN proprju ON feast.proprju_id=proprju.proprju_id\n" +
                    ") f  on m.feast_id=f.feast_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  grade on f.grd_id = grade.grd_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  colour on f.col_id = colour.col_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM komunPars\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN komun ON komunPars.kmn_id=komun.kmn_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para1 FROM parameters) p1 ON komunPars.p1_id=p1.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para2 FROM parameters) p2 ON komunPars.p2_id=p2.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para3 FROM parameters) p3 ON komunPars.p3_id=p3.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para4 FROM parameters) p4 ON komunPars.p4_id=p4.p_id\n" +
                    ") kp ON f.kmnpar_id = kp.kmnpar_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT feast_id, count(1) kmn_cnt FROM feast_komun GROUP BY feast_komun.feast_id) fk on f.feast_id = fk.feast_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM years\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN liturgicalTimes on years.lt_id = liturgicalTimes.lt_id\n" +
                    "WHERE ld_date = '" + dt + "'\n" +
                    ") ld ON 1\n" +
                    "UNION ALL\n" +
                    "SELECT f.feast_title, f.feast_subtitle, institute.inst_code, institute.inst_title, diocese.dioc_title, locality.loc_title, church.ch_title, f.proprju_id, f.desc_short, f.desc_long, grade.grd_rank, grade.grd_title, colour.col_title, kp.kmn_code, kp.kmn_title, kp.para1, kp.para2, kp.para3, kp.para4, ld.lt_title, ld.ld_litWeek, diocese.dioc_id, institute.inst_id, locality.loc_id, church.ch_id, f.feast_id, fk.kmn_cnt  FROM overrides\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM feast\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN proprju ON feast.proprju_id=proprju.proprju_id\n" +
                    ") f  on overrides.feast_id=f.feast_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  diocese on overrides.dioc_id = diocese.dioc_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  institute on 0 = diocese.dioc_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  locality on 0 = locality.loc_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  church on 0 = church.ch_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  grade on f.grd_id = grade.grd_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  colour on f.col_id = colour.col_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM komunPars\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN komun ON komunPars.kmn_id=komun.kmn_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para1 FROM parameters) p1 ON komunPars.p1_id=p1.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para2 FROM parameters) p2 ON komunPars.p2_id=p2.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para3 FROM parameters) p3 ON komunPars.p3_id=p3.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para4 FROM parameters) p4 ON komunPars.p4_id=p4.p_id\n" +
                    ") kp ON f.kmnpar_id = kp.kmnpar_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT feast_id, count(1) kmn_cnt FROM feast_komun GROUP BY feast_komun.feast_id) fk on f.feast_id = fk.feast_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM years\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN liturgicalTimes on years.lt_id = liturgicalTimes.lt_id\n" +
                    "WHERE ld_date = '" + dt + "'\n" +
                    ") ld ON 1\n" +
                    "WHERE ovr_date = '" + dt + "'\n" +
                    ")\n" +
                    "ORDER BY grd_rank DESC, case when dioc_id is NULL then 4 end, dioc_id ASC", null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                // fList.array();
                int doubleProprju = -1;
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    if (fullList == 0) {
                        // int tmpN = 0;
                        // tmpN = cursor.getInt(21);
                        // String tmp = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);

                        if ( ((dioc_id == 1) && (cursor.getInt(21) == 2)) || ((dioc_id == 1) && (cursor.getInt(21) == 3)) ||
                              ((dioc_id == 3) && (cursor.getInt(21) == 2)) || ((dioc_id == 2) && (cursor.getInt(21) == 3))
                        ) {
                            // if feast diocese <> user diocese
                            continue;   // omit one iteration
                        }

                        // tmpN = cursor.getInt(7);
                        if (doubleProprju == cursor.getInt(7))
                        {
                            // if feast has already been added (with a higher grade due to SQL sorting) do not add again
                            continue;
                        }

                        if (inst_id > 0) {
                            // if feast institute doesn't match user institute and feast institute is not empty
                            // tmpN = cursor.getInt(22);
                            if ( (inst_id != cursor.getInt(22)) && (cursor.getInt(22) > 0)) {
                                // if feast institute does not match user institute omit, but if institute field of feast is empty keep
                                continue;
                            }

                            if (inst_id == cursor.getInt(22)) {
                                // if feast has multiple entries, choose the matching institute entry
                                doubleProprju = cursor.getInt(7);
                            }
                        } else if (cursor.getInt(22) > 0) {
                            // omit feasts of institutes if user does not have an institute
                            continue;
                        }

                        // tmpN = cursor.getInt(23);
                        if (loc_id > 0) {
                            if ((cursor.getInt(23) != loc_id) && (cursor.getInt(23) > 0)){
                                // if user locality does not match feast locality
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else if (cursor.getInt(23) > 0) {
                            // if user did not select a locality, omit feasts of localities
                            continue;
                        }

                        // tmpN = cursor.getInt(24);
                        if (ch_id > 0) {
                            if ((cursor.getInt(24) != ch_id) && (cursor.getInt(24) > 0)){
                                // if user church does not match feast church
                                continue;
                            }
                        } else if (cursor.getInt(24) > 0) {
                            // if user did not select a church, omit feasts of church
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    FeastDay dList = new FeastDay(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5),
                            cursor.getString(6),cursor.getInt(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9),
                            cursor.getInt(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13),
                            cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17),
                            cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getInt(20),cursor.getInt(21),
                            cursor.getInt(22),cursor.getInt(23),cursor.getInt(24),cursor.getInt(25),
                            cursor.getInt(26));
                    feastList.add(dList);
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return feastList;
    }

    public String getFeastOverride(OrdoDay ordoDay, String date) {

        String overrideList = new String();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        try {
            Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(date);
            c.setTime(date1);
        } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        int dow = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT title FROM feast_override\n" +
                    "WHERE lt_id = " + ordoDay.lt_id + " AND week = " + ordoDay.ld_litWeek + " AND dow= " + dow,null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    overrideList = cursor.getString(0);
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return overrideList;
    }

    public ArrayList<AltKomun> getAltKomun(int feast_id, AltKomun original) {

        ArrayList<AltKomun> kmnList = new ArrayList<>();
        kmnList.add(original);

        try {
            db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT kp.kmn_code, kp.kmn_title, kp.para1, kp.para2, kp.para3, kp.para4  FROM (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM feast_komun\n" +
                    "WHERE feast_id=" + feast_id + "\n" +
                    ") fk\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN  (\n" +
                    "SELECT * FROM komunPars\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN komun ON komunPars.kmn_id=komun.kmn_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para1 FROM parameters) p1 ON komunPars.p1_id=p1.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para2 FROM parameters) p2 ON komunPars.p2_id=p2.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para3 FROM parameters) p3 ON komunPars.p3_id=p3.p_id\n" +
                    "LEFT JOIN (SELECT p_id, p_title as para4 FROM parameters) p4 ON komunPars.p4_id=p4.p_id\n" +
                    ") kp ON fk.kmnpar_id = kp.kmnpar_id",null);
            if (cursor != null) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    AltKomun dList = new AltKomun(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1),
                            cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                            cursor.getString(5));
                    kmnList.add(dList);
                }
                cursor.close();
                db.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return kmnList;
    }

    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = ctx.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = getDatabasePath();

        // if the path doesn't exist first, create it
        File f = new File(ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX);
        if (!f.exists())
            f.mkdir();

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }
    private static String getDatabasePath() {
        return ctx.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + DB_PATH_SUFFIX
                + DATABASE_NAME;
    }
    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        File dbFile = ctx.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
        if (!dbFile.exists()) {
            try {
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
                System.out.println("Copying sucess from Assets folder");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }
        return SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbFile.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close () {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
            super.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing I have done is that I have started using TortoiseSVN to version this Android Studio Project. Could it be impacting the build?

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused by minifyEnabled which was set to true. Setting it to false did the trick. Check this out:
[minifyEnabled causing app to crash on release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900434/minifyenabled-causing-app-to-crash-on-release-mode)